# If I met him, I would say "hello" to him

Tags: modal-verbs, conditional-constructions, conditionals

Friend: My father was at the same party you were yesterday.

1. Me: Really! If I **met** him, I **would say** "hello" to him.
2. Me: Really! If I **had met** him, I **would've  said** "hello" to him.

Q1) Which is correct? Or are they both correct?

My daughter appeared for an exam almost a month ago. The results came out yesterday. I **don't know** her results yet, **neither do I know** whether she studied hard for the exam. But,

3. I'm sure If she **studied** hard for it, she **would** pass it.

Q2) Is sentence (3) correct?

Comment: (1) is inappropriate for the scenario you describe; it implies that the speaker has not yet been in the situation where they might meet the father. If the exam results are out, you say "I'm sure she will have passed".

Answer (score 1):

> If I met him, I would say hello.

That is forward looking and logically conditional. It has the same meaning as

> If I meet him, I will say hello.

Notice the sequence of tenses and the parallelism of “would” and “will” (**NOT** “shall”).

> If I had met him, I would have said hello.

That is expressing something that did not happen. It is not a logical conditional. It means

> I did not meet him so I did not say hello as intended